# ErgoEmacs 25.1.1 crash when resize buffer (enlarge-window)

Tags: ergoemacs

Windows 7 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1.1. , package "ergoemacs".

Split any buffer. Then when I try to resize buffer (enlarge-window) by mouse I get the next message (in *Message* buffer):

```
Warning (ergoemacs): Increased max-specpdl-size to 2600 and max-lisp-eval-depth to 1600 for (lambda nil (interactive) nil (mouse-drag-mode-line last-command-event) (ergoemacs-command-loop--execute-modify-command-list (quote mouse-drag-mode-line)))
```

And when try again to resize buffer then Emacs is crash!

[image]

When I do same in pure emacs 25.1.1 - no  problem.

Comment: Do you get the crash when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe, from `emacs -Q`, to reproduce the crash. Any Emacs crash is an Emacs bug.

Comment: You already know from the error message that one or more functions in the ergoemacs package may be at fault.  Emacs does not maintain that package -- Xah Lee maintains ergoemacs.